# Css KeyFrames transform and fade effects

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to get to this:

[image]

But I'm getting this:

[image]

For some reason each animation individually works normal, but even if I set the opacity to 0 and after the transform my element returns to the same position and the same opacity before the animation

This is the open search component:

```
 const KeySearch2 = keyframes`
from { transform: translateY(-25px);opacity: 0; }
to   { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1;}
`;
export const SearchWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 70%;
  display: ${props => (props.test ? 'block' : 'none')};
  ${props =>
    props.test &&
    css`
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-name: ${KeySearch2};
    `}
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: red;
`;
```

and this is my component when my state is false or search component is closed:

```
const KeySearch = keyframes`
from { transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1; }
to   { transform: translateY(20px); opacity: 0;}
`;
export const NavUl = styled.ul`
  ${props =>
    props.test &&
    css`
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-name: ${KeySearch};
    `}

  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  svg {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
```

Comment: You will need an `animation-fill-mode: forwards` rule in there to preserve the last keyframe when the animation is complete.

Comment: @Lawrence have possibility after animation finished, make Component with display none, because with visibility, i got two components on the same position on the screen

Comment: And render Component on same position on the old component with visibility hidden